# Console output headers not aligned with columns

Tags: command-line

How can I make all command-line tools like `arp` or `netstat` show their output properly, so that the header line is aligned with the rest of the output?

[image]
[image]

The answer should *not* be manipulating the output itself (e.g. with `column -t` or similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with the translation. Whoever translated this command forgot to include the right amount of spaces, or launchpad or similar trimmed off the whitespace at some point. At any rate, you should report this as bugs for both netstat and arp.

If you run

```
LANG=C netstat | head
```

you should see the headers correctly aligned (in english).

Comment: thanks, that really worked, and now I know that was not a general Ubuntu bug.